# Is there a term for querying last known state of object in db's such as elasticsearch/kibana or powerbi?

Tags: elasticsearch, powerbi, kibana

So this example would be for any interactive dashboard like Kibana or PowerBI.

So say I have a vehicle 556 in a fleet of vehicles.
at 08:41:50 said vehicle generates an alarm (Engine overheated)

`2021-04-21T08:41:50 Priority 2 alarm - Vehicle 556 - Engine overheating`

I would like to then be able to click on this alarm, and get a dashboard which would show me known states from the vehicle at the time of the event.
e.g. speed of vehicle, accelaration percentage, braking percentage, and off course data which would come from other datasources, like weather information, driver etc.

So from the dashboard, I would expect based on below logs to see the following:

```
Vehicle: 556
Datetime: 2021-04-21 08:41:50
Speed: 42mph
Accelaration: 70%
Braking: 65%
Weather: Sunny, 80 deg
Other alarms: Engine fan stalled
```

```
2021-04-21T06:35:50 info - Weather - Sunny 75 deg
2021-04-21T07:35:50 info - Weather - Sunny 78 deg
2021-04-21T08:34:23 Priority 1 alarm - Vehicle 556 - Engine fan stalled
2021-04-21T08:35:50 info - Weather - Sunny 80 deg
2021-04-21T08:41:38 info - Vehicle 556 - Acceleration: 100%
2021-04-21T08:41:38 info - Vehicle 556 - Braking: 40%
2021-04-21T08:41:38 info - Vehicle 556 - Speed 24 mph
2021-04-21T08:41:42 info - Vehicle 556 - Acceleration: 97%
2021-04-21T08:41:42 info - Vehicle 556 - Braking: 50%
2021-04-21T08:41:42 info - Vehicle 556 - Speed 38 mph
2021-04-21T08:41:45 info - Vehicle 556 - Acceleration: 70%
2021-04-21T08:41:45 info - Vehicle 556 - Braking: 65%
2021-04-21T08:41:45 info - Vehicle 556 - Speed 42 mph
2021-04-21T08:41:50 Priority 2 alarm - Vehicle 556 - Engine overheating
```

For "bonus points" being able to then click the last known speed, and see a log which shows the last e.g. 10 logs regarding vehicle speed would also be nice.

But is this a thing in any database or specifically powerbi or elasticsearch/kibana
or would this require a custom created application-dashboard.
or is it indeed just because I don't know the right search term

Comment: In DB world  there are rows. The "last state of object" is simply a last row for particular column defined as partition(here the one containing "Vehicle 556" sorted by date desending). It could be called  *groupwise max* and often is implemented with analytics functions like `ROW_NUMBER`: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col ORDER BY date_col DESC) AS rn FROM  tab) sub WHERE sub.rn = 1`

Comment: have you looked at Grafana? It supports Elastic as a data store and lets you have parametrised graphs

Comment: Your question sounds more like a JIRA story (with implied knowledge of the environment, such as back end data source structure) than a real technical problem.

Answer (score 1):

For Power BI, there's a useful function LASTNONBLANKVALUE which can handle this.  The best documentation source (DAX Guide) for this is below, it includes the product documentation plus a live sandpit:

https://dax.guide/lastnonblankvalue/

For your scenario, I imagine using the timestamp for the 1st parameter (ColumnName), then the 3rd segment of the log text (e.g. a derived column with values like "Speed 42 mph") for the 2nd parameter.

I would build a set of DAX columns to prepare the data, using CALCULATE to restrict the set of rows considered. DAX Measures might be more flexible and dynamic, but are much more abstract to develop and query performance can suffer if they are complex.

Here's an example to get the Last Speed for each non-info Log row. I assume some data transformation to get helper columns for Vehicle etc.

```
Last Speed = 
VAR v_Timestamp_Max = LogTable[Timestamp]
VAR v_Vehicle = LogTable[Vehicle]
RETURN
IF ( LogTable[Level] <> "info" , 
    CALCULATE (
        LASTNONBLANKVALUE ( LogTable[Timestamp], MAX ( LogTable[Value] ) ),
        ALL ( LogTable ),
        LogTable[Timestamp] < v_Timestamp_Max,
        LogTable[Vehicle] = v_Vehicle,
        LogTable[Value Type] = "Speed"
    )
)
```